# lisp and writing a simple database

Tags: database, lisp

can anyone help me write a simple database?

```
[define database   
  [list [new Album  
                "The White Album"  
                 "The Beatles"  
                 "Rock"]  
        [new Album   
                "Collected"   
                "Massive Attack"   
                "Bristol sound"]    
        [new "Idlewild"     
                "Outkast"   
                "Soundtrack"]       
                ... etc ...]]
```

Writing accessors

You can access the fields of an album object (call it a) by saying a.title, a.artist, or a.genre.  But ".artist" isn't a procedure and sometimes it's useful to have a procedures that take album objects and return their title, artist, or genre.  So we'll start by writing them.

Write three procedures, title, artist, and genre, that, given an Album object as input, return its title, artist, and genre, respectively.  Include a test case for each to show that it works, e.g. [title [new Album "a" "b" "c"]] ought to output "a".

---

[define database
[list [new Album
“break up”
“Mario”
“R&B]]]
[title [new album]]

Comment: Looks like homework to me. We're not here to do your homework for you. Write some code.

Comment: I'm confused.  Can't you just hardcode a series of CARs and CDRs to select the item in question?  What's the actual format of an Album?  Is it a list of some sort?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you read the "[Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/)".
[Chapter 3 Practical: A Simple Database](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html) may help you to solve your problem.